# node-cron: Cron tick firing every second

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-cron

I'm using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to attempt to run a function at a specific time.

The function should fire at 10:00 on a weekday.

```
import { CronJob } from 'cron'

new CronJob('00 00 10  * * 1-5', function() {
  console.log('Fired');
})
```

When I run this code the function fires every second instead of once at a specified time.

[I filed a bug for this](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/issues/235) a while ago, but nobody has responded.

Comment: it is weird, since the syntax seems to be consistent with the format given in the [node-cron page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

Comment: The bug you filed has a completely different code example in it. Also there is nothing in your code example that tells it to run, so you wouldn't see any output...